# SD Card suddenly not recognized?

Tags: sd-card, file-system, xiaomi

Xiaomis Redmi 8 stopped recognizing a 128gb SD card by SanDisk a few months after first usage.
The card is not broken, neither is the phones slot.
The card works fine in my Samsung M20 and other cards work for the phone.

I guess the file system is the reason, but the phone couldn't format it in a way it is recognizeable again.

How do I know what file system the SD is using and which the phone needs?
And what else could be the problem?

Have a nice day

Comment: can you see it *'adb shell sm list-volumes public'* or *'adb shell grep media_rw /proc/mounts'* is mounted?